# Import csv file is not working as expected with azure data studio

Tags: sql, csv, import, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to import some csv  files with azure data studio but after user the import wizard tool this  did not fill the columns in the right way it just create 2 columns and put all the data I'm those by the way is working fine with txt files.  Any advice about what can be wrong with the format if my files?

Comment: Haha, I just get an infinite loading screen once I get the the actual insertion. It reads the file fine. And you can't even leave a 1 star review. AZD is so far from being comparable to VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your csv in excel's comma delimited, csv macintosh, csv ms-dos or UTF-8 csv format?  Sometimes I run into issues with this and the delimiters get messed up which it sounds like is your issue.  I always recommend UTF-8 for universality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JMeyer Data Science but the format is already  UTF-8

Comment: i think the product is buggy and support team is not looking after it well. I have an issue which opened in 2019, it is closed and reappear in 2020. On one from the team seems care to check in detail and fix it. maybe consider another tool for your development.